# Why is my input variable adding to itself? Python

Tags: python, variables

I have made this simple password generator with the option to choose the length of the password. It seems to randomly add the length to itself however, so if I keep choosing a length of 5 it will occasionally output a password of 10 characters and then go back to 5.

```
import random

randomnums = []
checker = [0, 0, 0, 0] ##Make sure there are upper, lower case, symbols and numbers.

while True:

    length = input("How long do you want your password?: ")
    
    if length.isdigit() == False:
        print("please enter a number..\n")
    elif int(int(length)) < 4:
        print("Please enter a length of 4 or greater...\n")
    else:
        break


while checker[0] == 0 or checker[1] == 0 or checker[2] == 0 or checker[3] == 0:
    for i in range(0,int(length)):
        x = random.randrange(0, 4)    
        if   x ==  1: 
            randomnums.append(random.randrange(0, 10))
            checker[0] = 1
        elif x == 2:
            randomnums.append(random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))
            checker[1] = 1
        elif x == 3:
            randomnums.append(random.choice('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ'))
            checker[2] = 1
        else:
            randomnums.append(random.choice('!@#$%^&*()_+:"}|<>?'))
            checker[3] = 1
    

password = ''.join(map(str, randomnums)) ##join list to string
print(password)`
```

Comment: Your while loop verifying that you've got one of each type of character is repeating since you must not have gotten one of each type of character in the first pass

Comment: It seems like your code will continually add characters until the `while` condition is true; regardless of the specified length. Think about it: the `for` loop exits after the `length`-many characters are added, then because of the `while`, it loops again, adding back to the *same list* as before.

Comment: I would guess that with `length` as a value of 5, you can get through the `for i in range(0,int(length)): loop and not grab exactly one of each of your `checker` flags.

Comment: You need your `randomnums = []` at the start of the `while` loop (so that if it needs to do more than one iteration, then the list is reset to an empty list at the start of subsequent iterations, rather than continuing to append to the same list).

Comment: what you should do instead is create a list of 4 characters by choosing some upper, lower case letter, a symbol and a number that and then filling up the list up to the `length` by `random.choice`'ing from all possible characters then finally `random.shuffling` the end result.

Comment: @Boris I'm sure there are various ways to fundamentally change the algorithm, but the bug fix to the existing algorithm is simply to move the initialisation of `randomnums` as indicated in my comment above.

Comment: @alani I wasn't responding to your comment, I was telling EddyW how to improve his program

Comment: @Boris Fair enough. It is certainly true that your suggested algorithm is guaranteed to produce a valid password in a single pass.

Answer (score 0):

You could get any multiple of `length` with this code. It adds `length` characters in the body until you got the required length. You should instead generate a password and check it, and if it is bad, repeat.